# Fedora 20 how to run script at the end of startup

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, fedora20

I am using **Fedora 20**. I have a two lines bash script needs to be run at the end of the startup. I want it to be **run automatically** each time when machine is startup.  How can I do this?

I tried **"sudo crontab -e"** to insert my executable script but it always gave me error teling me the the time is not right and cannot modify the file.

Comment: I don't have the full details now, but you need to write a systemd service that runs itself after normal startup. Also, more details about when exactly the script needs to run would be helpful.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Please use the `flag` link at the bottom of your question and ask the moderator to move it to http://unix.stackexchange.com. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't programming-related.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a Systemd unit file in **/usr/lib/systemd/system/<service_name>.service**. Here is a template:

```
[Unit]
Description=<description_string>

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=<working_directory>
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash <absolute_path_to_script>
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Replace anything in the angle brackets with your specific information. The 'WantedBy=multi-user.target' is the magic that tells Systemd to run your script on each start.

On the command line, tell Systemd to enable your service:

```
systemctl enable <service_name>.service
```

The next time you reboot your script should be run. Logs will be written to /var/log/messages.

Fedora has some basic documentation on unit files: [Systemd unit files](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd)

Answer (score 2):

You can append `/etc/rc.local` it runs just after the system starts up.

You may have to create it if doesn't exist:

[Check this answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/26898/what-is-the-auto-start-file-like-rclocal/)

Comment: I read somewhere saying it is not available/good for Fedora 20 and later.

Comment: you will have to enable it: `systemctl enable rc-local.service`

Comment: I got the following after I inserted my line to invoke my script:  $ sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).

Comment: Yes, I read that answer and tried it. I checked it to executable and added that bash line and also reboot my machine. The same as above.

Comment: same for me also, any solution you found?

Answer (score 2):

Charlie's answer is better but you can still use Tiago's answer.

Just don't forget if you want to use `/etc/rc.local` way, grant execution permission to this file after editing:

`chmod +x /etc/rc.local`